# Alternar texto e classe de um link quando clicado - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, eventos, click

Estou tentando fazer a delegação de um evento `click` à um link dentro de uma tabela, [como mostra este exemplo do jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rhqLbou9/):

O resultado obtido como podem ver, é:

- Ao clicar no link "**Ativar**", o evento `click` atribuído à classe `.activate` é disparado, alterando assim a classe do mesmo link para `.deactivate`.
- Ao clicar no link "**Desativar**", o evento `click` atribuído à classe `.activate` é disparado novamente mas não acontecendo nada, e o correto seria a execução do evento `click` alterando novamente a sua classe para `.activate`.

Para um melhor entendimento, por favor abram o link do [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rhqLbou9/).

Pegando alguns exemplos que já havia feito, e pesquisando sobre casos parecidos com o meu, descobri que deveria delegar o evento da seguinte forma:

```
$(document).on("click", "#element", function (e) {});
```

No entanto não obtive o resultado esperado, como podem ver [neste outro exemplo do jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apvLjx8k/).
Estou à disposição para acrescentar mais informações, se necessário.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu acho que o melhor seria fazer isso numa só função utilizando um `if/else` e apontando o clique para uma `class` (que neste caso não poderia ser um `id` pois isto vai ser utilizado mais que uma vez) que não seja modificada devido a interacções do usuário para evitar conflitos, como neste exemplo abaixo:

```js
$('.status').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('ativar')) {
        $(this).removeClass('ativar').addClass('desativar').text('Ativar');
    }
    else {
        $(this).removeClass('desativar').addClass('ativar').text('Desativar');
    }
});
```

```css
th,td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Titulo 1</th>
                <th>Titulo 2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Campo 1</td>
                <td>Campo 2</td>
                <td><a href="#" class="status">Ativar</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Campo 3</td>
                <td>Campo 4</td>
                <td><a href="#" class="status">Ativar</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente para mim!

Answer (score 5):

O teu código estava certo! Só esqueceste de juntar o jQuery no jsFiddle.

Se quiseres comprimir ainda mais o código podes fazer assim:

```
$('.content tbody').on("click", ".activate, .deactivate", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var ativo = $(this).hasClass('activate');
    $(this).html(ativo ? "Desativar" : "Ativar").toggleClass("activate deactivate");
});
```

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/am2h9149/

Comment: Nossa! uma solução ainda mais simples, muito obrigado! Com certeza será de grande utilidade. :)